# Can multiple threads reading the same property file in Java cause performance issues?

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I am creating multiple threads and all the threads read the same property file (there is no write operation done to property file). Will this cause performance overhead since the same property file is read multiple times by multiple threads?

Comment: How often do you read this file?

Comment: so long as you're not writing, I wouldn't say there would be any concurrency issues

Comment: This things are working bottom up - did you notice that performance of your system is suffering from the thread contention? It's useless to guess especially with no data provided - do you have one thread? one hundred threads?

Comment: I have about 600 rows of data in a property file and i would say about 40-50 threads concurrently accessing the same

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to [load the properties file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) once and use the same [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instance by all the threads.

Load once reduce the disk access:

- better performance for this application
- better availability of the entire system

Multiple reading is not a concurrency problem.

A comment of [didierc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769720/didierc) highlight a possible bottleneck: each access to Properties is synchronized, so when thread read a value, all the other may wait.

To avoid this, you may confine the use of the `Properties` in the constructor or initialization of your threads. Don't use `p.getProperty( XXX )` in a loop inside the `Thread.run()` methods.

Comment: Will it be the same property object reference shared by mutliple threads and can it cause issues ?

Comment: @raghuramgururajan it's your choice to make. You could try both solutions and see what works best in terms of speed and memory consumption, but I'm afraid that you will have to copy the property list explicitely accross the threads if you want to avoid concurrent access to the same object instance. Note that `Properties` inherits from `Hashtable`, which is synchronised.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it depends". Mostly it depends on how much work each thread does in addition to reading the properties file. If each thread does much work in addition to reading the file, performance will not be much affected.

You should be more concerned about potential correctness problems: if different threads used different properties, would the program behave correctly? If not, your program has a race hazard bug: if the property file is altered (or deleted) while the program runs, some threads could use different properties and so produce an incorrect computation.

Property files are used for program configuration. Programs typically read all their configuration information soon after they start, before doing any real work. they can therefore *fail fast* if the configuration is faulty.You probably ought to do likewise, treating the spawning of threads as the *real work* to do later. This also ensures a user of your program gets only one error message per fault in the configuration, rather than one message per thread.